# Find which revision deleted a file in git

Tags: git

You can find where a file was modified using

```
git log -- pathspec
```

but that stops on revision that does not contain any files matching `pathspec`. Well, the file in question was removed, so the last revision does not contain it, so it stops immediately. So how do I find the revision where the file was deleted?

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
git log --full-history -- pathspec
```

to prevent the undesired history simplification.